# nginx - laravel - hhvm-Fastcgi get error 500

Tags: php, nginx, laravel, laravel-4, hhvm

I install a LEMP server in ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64
whit HHVM Fastcgi Service
and i install laravel via laravel.phar ( and test via composer too )
when in get my site in brwoser do not display any error but in chrome developer console get error 500
[image]

i can't see any error in error.log file ( laravel - hhvm , nginx )

the storage directory Permissions is 777

and my nginx.conf and vhosts file have basic configuration

when i use PHP CLI or hhvm command it's worked good

thanks for help me :)

my location block

```
location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_keep_conn on;
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include        fastcgi_params;
```

Comment: Take a look at [fideloper's install guide](http://fideloper.com/hhvm-nginx-laravel) as well as [the servers for hackers nginx guide](http://serversforhackers.com/editions/2014/03/25/nginx/) and put the two together.  If you install nginx then hhvm, and you are using `hhvm 3.*` then HHVM will automatically add in a `hhvm.conf` file to `/etc/nginx/` then all you have to do is `include hhvm.conf` inside your server block.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with HHVM is it doesn't show much error, You have to keep watching the HHVM or Laravel error logs.

> You'll want to pay close attention to your error logs. HHVM doesn't
>   report errors to the browser by default.

Check the HHVM logs!

```
$ tail -n 50 -f /var/log/hhvm/error.log
```

Check your Laravel logs!

```
$ tail -n 50 -f /path/to/laravel/app/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

---

**config reference**

Create a file `/etc/nginx/hhvm.conf` if it doesn't exist yet. Insert the ff:

```
location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Then include it on your nginx virtual host config.
eg. `/etc/nginx/sites-available/laravel`

Now add this for Laravel, edit as needed:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /vagrant/laravel/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name localhost;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.laravel-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/locahost.laravel-error.log error;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php?\$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;      

    include hhvm.conf;  # INCLUDE HHVM HERE

    # Deny .htaccess file access
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Then reload Nginx:

```
$ sudo service nginx reload
```

Comment: thanks @majidarif all ngnix config is tested okay , but when i install laravel connt run int from browser ! it's currently work in CLI

Comment: @user1873569 HHVM does not show errors on the browser by default. check my updated answer.

Comment: in no have any error on laravel.log but in  hhvm/error.log have error Fatal error: unexpected St13runtime_error: locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
then fix it before install laravel

Comment: @hannesvdvreken i know about it , and fixed this error ! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `X-Powered-By` header is set by HHVM I assume your NGINX is configured correct. A 500 error mostly comes from a syntax error or an exception thrown in your application. Maybe your fastcgi settings in NGINX are still wrong. What's inside the `location *\.php` block?

Try for a less error-prone setup and run `php artisan serve` to locally host your project.

Comment: when i add a single file of php for example : `` <?php echo 'test okay'; `` it's word currently

Comment: artisan use php -S command to run a web server when install HHVM and user cli have error hhvm connot accept -S and show syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You can modify Laravel's handle exception class to display the errors while HHVM is being used.

Full details here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8744#issue-76454458

I have tested this and It works well on Laravel 5.2/5.3 on Homestead with HHVM.