# laravel 5 show blank page on server error (and no laravel log), running with hhvm and nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5, hhvm

I followed [Fideloper post](http://fideloper.com/hhvm-nginx-laravel) about running `laravel` with hhvm, step by step. There are two projects hosted on my server, one is my blog which is based on [wardrobe](http://wardrobecms.com/) (laravel 4.1), and another project with laravel 5.

My blog has no issue with server errors and laravel log file; But the other project cannot create log files, and it won't show error page because of that.

I double checked `storage` folder permission. It is `777`.

When I run `php artisan serve` (native php, not hhvm) and browse to it, the error page showed up, and log file was created. So something is wrong with hhvm I think.

How can I fix blank page, when running `laravel 5` with `hhvm`, and an error occurred? How can I bring back the error page (or whoops page)

**P.S.** I have read related question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240375/nginx-laravel-hhvm-fastcgi-get-error-500) and still have the problem.

**P.S.S.** If any information needed ask me and I will update the question.

Comment: You will probably have better luck asking this question on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) which is for system administration questions.

Comment: some grammar fixes.
I think what's needed from the OP is clarification as to what kind of help is sought for.

Comment: HHVM (unfortunately) logs fatal errors to `/var/log/hhvm/error.log`.

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet? I think I've got the same problem. I'm in Homestead and Lumen with HHVM. I get a blank page, no errors show. I can see the errors in `/var/log/hhvm/error.log` though.

Comment: I figured out what is going on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789945/when-i-turn-on-hhvm-on-homestead-i-dont-get-any-syntax-error-or-missing-clas/30226587#30226587

Comment: @DavidGraham please post it as an answer
Thank you by the way

Comment: Done. I put up a detailed answer, and made a few adjustments, see answer below

Comment: Updated answer to be more Laravel specific. Also reported this issue/fix on the Laravel github project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suffered the same problem when I installed Laravel Homestead with HHVM. If you enter some random junk like `sdfkjl` into your routes file you'll get a blank page (however, if add a semi-colon `sdfkjl;` you get error output). The errors are being logged at `/var/log/hhvm/error.log` but they don't go to the browser, instead you just get a blank page. It appears this is intentional behavior for HHVM. It also appears Laravel tries to handle these but doesn't catch some of the fatals sent by HHVM. Thanks to clues from [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4818) I decided to make some slight changes to Laravel's `Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php` to see if I could get it to catch all of these fatals:

First, update your `/etc/hhvm/php.ini` and add these settings:

```
hhvm.server.implicit_flush = true
hhvm.error_handling.call_user_handler_on_fatals = true
```

Before modifying a package source, let's remove the `vendor\compiled.php` with this artisan command:

```
$ php artisan clear-compiled
```

And let's set the environment sessons to array:

in your *.env*

```
SESSION_DRIVER=array
```

(You may also need to clear all the random-looking session files in *storage/framework/sessions*)

Now any changes we make to the Laravel package source will immediately reflect. Let's update a few things in the HandleExceptions class:

in *vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php*

```
// **** Add this to hold fatal error
protected static $fatalError = null;

...

public function handleError($level, $message, $file = '', $line = 0, $context = array())
{

   // **** Add this, loads fatal error
   if ($level & (1 << 24)) {
        self::$fatalError = array(
            'message' => $message,
            'type' => $level,
            'file' => $file,
            'line' => $line
        );
    }   

    if (error_reporting() & $level)
    {
        throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $level, $file, $line);
    }
} 

...   

// *** Update this function so it can handle the fatal
public function handleShutdown()
{
    $error = error_get_last();

    if(self::$fatalError){
        $error = self::$fatalError;
    }

    if ( ! is_null($error) && $this->isFatal($error['type']))
    {
        $this->handleException($this->fatalExceptionFromError($error, 0));
    }
}

...

protected function isFatal($type)
{
    // *** Add type 16777217 that HVVM returns for fatal
    return in_array($type, [16777217, E_ERROR, E_CORE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_PARSE]);
}

...
```

Now type the random junk (no semi-colon) in your routes folder and you'll see the fatal display. I have now [reported this issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8744) to Taylor on the Laravel github. If you are in Lumen, I've got a [solution here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/lumen-debug-mode-not-showing-stack-trace?page=1#reply-60138) that will work until Lumen gets fixed as well.

Comment: Thanks alot! After surfing the whole websites that made the debugging to a new level

Answer (score -1):

I also got the same issue. Give `755` permission to entire laravel project it's work for me

anyway you can check hhvm error log, run

```
$tail -n 50 -f /var/log/hhvm/error.log
```

Comment: 777 on everything is both dangerous and unnecessary. There are much better ways to set permissions.

Comment: @ceejayoz sorry it is not 777 it should be 755, is it ok?

Comment: You're better of either using ACL or chown to allow the webserver to write to the `storage` directories.