# When I turn on "hhvm" on Homestead, I don't get any syntax error or missing class error, just blank page

Tags: hhvm

I am using homestead as my development environment, I turned on the hhvm option for the site

```
sites:
- map: homestead.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/wheremyprojectis
  hhvm: true
```

I found that when there is an exception, everything is fine, but If I forgot to use namespace, got syntax error in the blade templates, I got nothing, blank page. I go check the logs and still nothing, the debug option is true. It's quite frustrating until I turned off the hhvm option.

I know it is not a big deal, but I still want to know is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same problem. I searched around and found that it seems to be intentional:

- https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4818
- https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/2571

Now you can poke through the github issues mentioned above, as well as these stackoverflow questions:

- [Display fatal/notice errors in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24524222/display-fatal-notice-errors-in-browser)
- [hhvm-fastcgi + nginx how to make it display fatal errors in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086903/hhvm-fastcgi-nginx-how-to-make-it-display-fatal-errors-in-the-browser)
- [laravel 5 show blank page on server error (and no laravel log), running with hhvm and nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264326/laravel-5-show-blank-page-on-server-error-and-no-laravel-log-running-with-hhv/30238538#30238538)

For the time being, it ultimately boils down to writing your own handler, which isn't too bad. You can also tail the errors at `/var/log/hhvm/error.log`. Any errors that you intentionally want going to the browser you could of course handle using [Laravel's error handling and logging](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors#handling-errors).

**UPDATE:**
I reported this issue(and a fix) to the Laravel github here:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8744